# Any reason why this code may have corrupted couple of file while creating zip file

Tags: c#, zip, c#-ziparchive

The following code creates a zip file from S3 by pulling them into memory and write the final product to a file on disk. However, it is observer it corrupted few file (out of thousands) while creating the zip. I've checked, there is nothing wrong with files which got corrupted during the process, because same file(s) get zipped properly by other means. Any suggestions to fine tune the code?

Code:

```
public static async Task S3ToZip(List<string> pdfBatch, string zipPath, IAmazonS3 s3Client)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))
    {
        foreach (var file in pdfBatch)
        {
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = "sample-bucket",
                Key = file
            };
            using GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
            using Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream;
            ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Split('/')[^1]);
            using Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open();
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
            zipEntryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            zipEntryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
        archive.Dispose();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, I... What? You're opening a ZipArchive to write to a file, which is fine, but then copying an individual ZipArchiveEntry into that same file as well? So you'll write your raw request to the file, and then write the whole zip archive over the top of it? I can't see how that would ever work.

Comment: @canton7 Didn't understand this part "and then write the whole zip archive over the top of it", could you please explain?

Comment: I see you switched from custom library to standard .NET classes. But your solution is again very weird, I don't even know how it can even work. I suppose `zipEntryStream` not supports rewinding and when copied to `fileStream` breaks nothing. I think your main problem in this two statements `archive.Dispose(); fileStream.Close();` one is already handled by `using`, others should be done outside of scope and preferably with `using` too.

Comment: Hey @AlexeyRumyantsev, yes did switch to standard .NET class.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev Could you please point out the dents and how do I go about rectifying them?

Comment: @Aniruddha You passed the `fileStream` to the `ZipArchive` constructor. That tells `ZipArchive` to write to that `FileStream`. This will be done by `archive.Dispose()` if not earlier. Since you've told the `ZipArchive` to write to the file, it's very odd (and broken) that you're then also writing to it yourself. Note that reading an `ZipArchiveEntry`'s stream gives you the *uncompressed* version, not the compressed version: it's what you just wrote from `responseStream`

Comment: @canton7 I suppose that two lines do nothing, because all archives must be broken, not some out of thousands.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev It looks like `ZipArchive.Dispose()` first rewinds `fileStream` to the beginning. So you've got a problem if the uncompressed version of the file is longer than the full compressed archive (including header, etc): then some data from the uncompressed file won't be overwritten by `ZipArchive`, and will be left at the end of the file, corrupting it. That might explain why it only bites some of the time.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, didn't see that author repeats his mistake from previous question and uses `OpenOrCreate` again. Changed answer according to your note.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev The `FileMode` won't matter here: that would only come into effect if the FileStream was opened over a file which already had some data in it, but that isn't happening here. Instead, the truncation would need to happen between OP writing the uncompressed data to the file, and then the compressed archive, and `FileMode` won't help with that.

Comment: @canton7 `zipPath` is only output, data is taken from S3 service, there is no reading and writing to same file here. But ensuring that output is truncated is good practice here.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev I don't follow. I never said that data was read from the file. Agreed that ensuring the file is truncated is good practice, but that won't affect the specific issue OP is seeing.

Comment: @canton7 I think that writing to `FileStream` occurs directly when you write to stream opened by `ZipArchiveEntry`. Disposing `zipArchive` just finalizing all things and releasing resources. It has streaming nature to have small memory footprint, in your case it must accumulate or data before dumping it to disk, which looks very unlikely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230506/discussion-between-canton7-and-alexey-rumyantsev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `Dispose()` or `Close()` explicitly, let `using` do all the job. And you don't need to write anything to `fileStream` writing to `ZipArchiveEntry`stream does it under the hood. You also need to use `FileMode.Create` to guarantee that your file is always truncated before writing to it. Also as you only creating archive not updating it, you should use `ZipArchiveMode.Create` to enable memory efficient streaming (thanks to @canton7 for some deep diving in details of zip archive format).

```
public static async Task S3ToZip(List<string> pdfBatch, string zipPath, IAmazonS3 s3Client)
{
    using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
    
    foreach (var file in pdfBatch)
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "sample-bucket",
            Key = file
        };
        using GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
        using Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream;
        ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.Split('/')[^1]);
        using Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open();
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
    }         
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks to yourself and canton. You both have been so helpful and explanatory. This is the first time someone being so helpful on SO

Comment: Did't get any file corrupted. Thanks! :)